# Adiabatic expansion paradox

Tags: thermodynamics, work, adiabatic

If we let a gas expand against vacuum with a piston which is not weightless then can we call it free expansion? If yes then there is a paradox . Work done by a gas is said to be = -p( external) multiplied by dv. For the current discussion I will write it as $-F(external) × ds$. This says that work done should be 0 in any kind of free expansion. If the free expansion is adiabatic, then internal energy should be constant. Piston which is initially at rest will move during expansion which means it gains kinetic energy. If internal energy of gas remains constant and the piston gets kinetic energy, then the system gets an excess of kinetic energy.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149017/discussion-on-question-by-sanjoy-kundu-adiabatic-expansion-paradox); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.